# Question on trigonometric notation (specifically wrt parentheses)

Tags: trigonometry, notation

1. $\sin x = \sin(x)$
2. $\sin xy = \sin(x*y)$
3. $\sin xy = y\sin(x)$
4. $\sin x*y = \sin(x*y)$
5. $\sin x*y = y\sin(x)$

#1 is a given, since the whole field discusses "trigonometric functions"

If #2 were the conventional understanding of the notation, which seems to be the case from a cursory look at various textbooks, then #3 would be at odds, from a semantic perspective, with #2, in which case it would be odd for anyone to assume that #3 should be the correct way to understand the given notation. Am I correct in assuming that #2, not #3, is the norm and nobody really serious about the topic in question assumes #3?

If #2 were a variant of #4, then there would be no confusion as to the meaning of the notation; however I've yet to see any expression that would utilize the * as in #4 to express sin(xy). Am I correct to assume that #4 is not part of conventional notation?

I apologize if this seems like a strange question.

Comment: Parentheses eliminate ambiguity, but they can add visual clutter that impedes readability. An author has some freedom —and responsibility— in balancing these aspects. (Peers/advisors/editors may weigh in on the effectiveness of one's choices.) ... Convention seems okay w/removing parentheses about a product when constants are involved: $\sin2x$, $\cos n\pi y$, $\tan\lambda z$. While $\sin xy$ for $\sin(xy)$ isn't terrible in isolation —a thoughtful author would've used $y\sin x$ if $(\sin x)(y)$ were intended— it might be confusing in complicated expressions. Do what best serves your audience.

Comment: I consider $1$, $2$ and $3$ fine and clear also without parentheses but in the cases $4$ and $5$ we need parentheses to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the expressions:

1. **$\sin(x) = \sin(x)$**  - This is a trigonometric identity and is correct.
2. *$\sin(xy) = \sin(x \cdot y)$* - This is the conventional understanding where ***xy*** represents the product of ***x*** and ***y***.
3. *$\sin(xy) = y \sin(x)$* -this seems to be an alternative interpretation wTere ***xy*** is understood as ***x*** times ***y***. This is not a conventional interpretation and could lead to confusion.
4. *$\sin(x \cdot y) = y \sin(x)$* -This uses the multiplication symbol ***(⋅)*** explicitly and is a valid expression, but it's not a standard notation in trigonometry.

In standard mathematical notation, when variables are written next to each other, it generally implies multiplication. The second expression ***(#2)*** is the conventional and widely accepted interpretation, where ***xy*** is understood as the product of ***x*** and ***y***. The third expression ***(#3)*** deviates from the convention and may lead to confusion.

The use of the asterisk **(*)** for multiplication is more common in computer programming and some specific mathematical contexts, but it's not the standard notation in general mathematics. So, ***#4*** is not a conventional notation either.